# How do I get xjc?

Tags: java, xml, xjc

So I've been looking at interfacing with xml files for a project I've been working on, and one of the things I want to do is generate java classes from a .dtd file.  After some searching, I found out that xjc should be able to do what I want, but I cannot for the life of me find out where to get the program itself.

I feel like the answer is sitting right in front of me, but my google-fu is really failing me hardcore right now...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got it when I installed java.  It is probably on your system right now.  Look in the directory where java, javac, etc are located.

Comment: ...wow.  It was really that simple.  I have two drives, with some of my program files on one and some on the other.  I had searched throughout the java folder on my E: drive, which is where the majority of my installations go, but had completely forgotten about the C: drive.
Also, as a side note, it looks like it was only in the java jdk folders, so you need the full jdk to make it work (in an effort to make this question at least slightly useful to other people)

Comment: it's not  in java/jdk distro starting from 9+

Comment: @Bogdan For certain questions, I think the answers should be deprecated.  I think at the time I wrote this answer I was highly competent in the subject matter, but it has moved so far off my radar that I no longer even understand the question.  In general, most answers to technical questions that are over 5 years old should be considered WRONG.

Answer (score 30):

Note that since Java 11, the JAXB was removed from the JDK. It has to be separately installed. There is a `bin` directory in the ZIP file where we can find the `xjc` and `schemagen` tools.

Download link:
https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jaxb-ri/

Comment: Beware: `xjc.bat` (of version 2.3.1) contains invalid settings, does not detect Java properly (uses `java` available from path instead of that one specified in `JAVA_HOME` path variable), does not work with Java 9 or later. So first, install java 1.8, then modify `jaxb-ri\bin\xjc.bat` and replace `/lib/` with `/mod/`, replace `%JAXB_HOME%/mod/javax.activation.jar;%JAXB_HOME%/lib/relaxngDatatype.jar` with `%JAXB_HOME%/mod/javax.activation-api.jar;%JAXB_HOME%/mod/relaxng-datatype.jar`, run `set JAVA_HOME=<path-to-java8-without-bin>`, then run `bin\xjc.bat` from `jaxb-ri` folder.

Comment: A downloaded the old JDK and just ran the command from the bin folder where xcj.exe is located.

Comment: Optionally you can add an jdk8 (below the jdk 11 or newer reference) to your path and it will be found as well

Comment: can you update your link to https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jaxb-ri/ yours doesn't work on java 17, at the time of this writing 4.x is the newest

Answer (score 4):

Its part of the JDK. Check your Java bin folder.

Comment: it is not supported in jdk any more

Comment: it is not supported as of jdk 11 any more

Answer (score 2):

I had some problems while installing `xjc` manually downloaded, as suggested in one of the answers and I succeed with a `sudo apt-get install jaxb` as suggested by my Linux terminal :)

Answer (score 1):

xjc is a tool in JAXB which is in Java SE, Java EE and Java Web Services and i'm sure many more. Read up on [JAXB](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0440__XML/0100__JAXB.htm) Here

Answer (score 1):

It's available here: https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jaxb-ri/ on the Download section

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ubuntu and java version is less than 9, then this may help

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/xjc xjc /your_java_home_path/bin/xjc 100
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking to parse XML as a one off, and you don't want to deal with downloading random binaries, or messing about with your PATH, you can easily get access to `xjc` by installing any JDK 1.8 version.

To do this nice and easily, use [SDKMAN](https://sdkman.io/)

Once it's installed, run `sdk install java 8.0.332-zulu` to install Java 8, you probably don't want to set it as your default, so once the install is done run `sdk use java 8.0.332-zulu` and you're good to.